# Get updated position of the element

Tags: jquery

I have a div inside a parent div, and when I drag it and then click a button I want to show the left value of the element being dragged.

The way my code is now, it just reads it at the beginning of page load, but if I drag the div the position left does not update.

```
<div id="draggableHolder">
<div id="draggable"><p>drag me around</p></div>
</div>



$('#draggable').draggable({axis: 'x'});

var position = $('#draggable').position();

$('button').on('click', function() {
     console.log(position.left);
});
```

Basically now I always get 0, there is no update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this -

```
console.log($('#draggable').position().left);
```

- http://api.jquery.com/position/

Comment: Makes sense. Shouldn't have stored it in a variable. Thanks.

Comment: that's right. Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5rRMu/) for who want to make a quick test.